# How to do invoice text base reporting in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, templates, report

I would like to build invoice text base to have following format:

https://gist.github.com/samnang/9d35a8622af5779a9228

But when I try to render as text format from my controller, then I find out it's very to control how it look because those text are dynamic like company name could be short or long. I don't want to other texts move position depend on something else because those format will be sent to print company to match print out paper.

Is there any examples, gems, or suggestions how to build invoice text base?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to truncate some fields to fit into the defined tab area.  If you allocate 20 characters of description data, then you need to only allow 20 characters on the output `your_text[0..19]`

I think working in text for this type of work is going to be overly complex, and you should look at converting the output to pdf to have more control.  Take a look at https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn